# npm errors while installing

Tags: apt, gnome-terminal, nodejs, npm

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04LTS dual-booted with Windows 10 on my ASUS X552EA laptop running on AMD processors. I've been trying to install some packages on my system with npm. The command I used was a simple,

```
npm install
```

after changing to the directory of my package. I get a few warnings and a lot of errors.
[image]

I don't have a lot of experience in linux so I don't understand these errors, or the instructions that it passes.
Could someone help me understand and fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> **You use an *old version* of [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)!**

---

#### How To Install the Distro-Stable Version

*Ubuntu 16.04LTS* contains a version of Node.js in its default repositories that can be used to easily. The version of your **Node.js** in the repositories is 4.2.6 and the npm version 3.5.2. This will not be the latest version, but it should be quite stable.

In order to get the newest version of Node.js, you just have to **use the `apt` package manager**. You should refresh your local package index prior and then install from the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

If the package in the repositories suits your needs, this is all that you need to do to get set up with Node.js. In most cases, you'll also want to also install **npm**, which is *the Node.js package manager*. You can do this by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

This will allow you to easily install modules and packages to use with Node.js.

#### Helpful resources

- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=install+node.js+on+ubuntu
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302436/install-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-10
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server
- https://www.elastichosts.com/blog/how-to-install-nodejs-on-ubuntu/
- http://davidtsadler.com/archives/2012/05/06/installing-node-js-on-ubuntu/

Comment: This is how I installed them. Tried this again just now. It says it's already the latest version. I didn't use the default package, but installed them. NodeJS version - 4.2.6, npm version - 3.5.2

Comment: If you have the newest version of NodeJS and npm, it's most likely a problem with the `electron-prebuilt` package, not with npm itself.

Comment: I checked that, electron-prebuild isn't there in the path displayed on the terminal. It's supposed to be there, right?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't installed because you get the error warnings!

Comment: I add an new issue on GitHub: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-prebuilt/issues/153. Ask there for possible solutions. ;-)